# Redirect loop to non-existent URI path

Tags: apache, http, nginx

Yesterday my paid hosting started to behave weirdly. Using Chrome, I query directory listing of my web server, and as first step *something* redirects me to the non-existent *relative* path, then, it returns me back to original path, but then contents are restored.

It does literally the following (I removed host name)

**Request 1**

```
GET /software/roms HTTP/1.1
Host: www.*****
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

**Response 1**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /KXSQZ/software/roms
```

**Request 2**

```
GET /KXSQZ/software/roms HTTP/1.1
Host: www.******
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

**Response 2**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /software/roms
```

**Request 3**

```
GET /software/roms HTTP/1.1
Host: www.******
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Response 3**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Sun, 27 Aug 2017 17:24:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.*******/software/roms/
...
```

**Request 4**

```
GET /software/roms/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.*****
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

**Response 4**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Sun, 27 Aug 2017 18:04:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

You can see that first two redirects do not use Nginx server header, thus I suspect it is not my server which responds. Also, my virtual hosted server does not have any log entry for the 302/301 redirects, it only shows 200.

I tried loading page several times, and it gives **new** nonexistent path every time (e.g. now it is /XmnYZ/).

Let me explain my setup - I have several devices: PC and another IoT device which does not understand redirects (and that's why I caught the issue). Both devices get same issue, thus it is not that my PC with Chrome is having some virus. IoT device, which can not have virus (it is custom platform) exhibits the same problems.

Is it a traffic interception? Is it a virus - then where? Where to look for the issue and resolution?

Comment: if it's not nginx, then try stop nginx and look at result. did you see any differences in headers between request 1 and request 4, I mean the server must somehow know that there is no need for redirection (otherwise there will be an infinite loop of redirection)?

Comment: Will try stopping hosted service. Currently it seems I have no redirects (but I reported tech problem to hosting company support about 1hr ago - maybe they fixed it). No, there's no difference in headers, I think there's some "entrance" (or intermediary) device which redirects new requests to these strange paths for monitoring purposes, and then passes requests from the same host on the same port with the same headers for normal service.

Comment: Ok, it happened again. I stopped hosting service, and nothing loads. Thus it is something at the hosting side - nginx or apache. Good thing that following your advice I restarted the service, maybe this restart will help eliminate the issues. Let's see

Comment: No luck, it happened again. What can I do to further troubleshoot the issue, or I am fully in the hands of the hosting company support? They already replied that "we do not see any issue in server logs" (of course as these redirects are not logged).

Comment: Did you see redirects when the service was stopped? Try add `die();` in the first line of your php. or try temporary delete your php at all.

Comment: I do not have PHP installed. I do not see redirects in web server logs at all even when started. It is integration of Nginx and Apache, but Nginx always replies with its server name, while when redirects happen there's no such header.

Comment: maybe you have cache in your `nginx`? try to disable cache temporary.